# Running a simple Python script from Ada program

Tags: python, ada, gnat

Does someone would have a simplest as possible way to run a Python script from the Ada project?

The Python script in this case only has a print in a loop, with a sleep, so each iteration it should print the arguments.

The Python script I'm using is

```
import sys
import time

for index in range(10):
    print(sys.argv)
    time.sleep(1)
```

On approach I am trying is running this one as a batch script, so using

```
with Text_IO;
with Interfaces.C; use Interfaces.C;
procedure systest2 is
   function Sys (Arg : Char_Array) return Integer;
   pragma Import(C, Sys, "system");
   Ret_Val : Integer;
begin
   Ret_Val := Sys(To_C("python testpy.py arg1 arg2"));
end systest2;
```

The problem is that the execution blocks the script, meaning that the Python printouts are only printed at the end of the execution, at once.

I know that there is a solution (to run Python from Ada) based on GNATCOLL, but I couldn't find any example to run it.

**Update**

Just to clarify.
So I will try to simplify a bit the question. I want to do the equivalent of this in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
  system("python testpy.py ddddd");
  return 0;
}
```

In this case it does not block the testpy.py printouts.

But I am doing this

```
with Interfaces.C; use Interfaces.C;
procedure systest2 is
   function Sys (Arg : Char_Array) return Integer;
   pragma Import(C, Sys, "system");
   Ret_Val : Integer;
begin
   Ret_Val := Sys(To_C("python testpy.py arg1 arg2"));
end systest2;
```

which blocks the testpy.py script until its end. This should not happen.

So, please, how could I fix this?

Comment: Not familiar with Ada but you should look into Pipes or some kind of IPC.

Comment: Well... the problem is exactly how to implement in Ada.

Comment: What does "which blocks the testpy.py script until its end" mean?  If it were blocking the script, it would not run.  Can you clarify that?

Comment: Since you are using the same system call in Ada and C, behavior should not be different. Both calls block until the Python call has returned. If you don't want it to block, you could do `"python testpy.py arg1 arg2 &"`.

Comment: I think this must depend on the OS. It works fine on macOS - that is, I see output once a second. Of course the Ada program can’t do anything until the Python script returns. Maybe you just need to say `python -u testpy.py arg1 arg2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is an example that might help (tested with GNAT CE 2019 on Linux). It's based on the `GNAT.Expect` package and the example that was given in one of [AdaCore's Gem articles](https://www.adacore.com/gems/gem-54). In the example, a new process is spawned and pipes are automatically connected.

Two remarks:

- It's important to run the python interpreter with I/O buffering disabled (using the `-u` option). If this is undesirable, then you can, alternatively, also use the flush option on the `print` statement in Python 3 i.e. `print(..., flush=True)`. When you don't disable the I/O buffering or flush the I/O buffer behind `print`, you will run into timeouts.
- The Python script is, for now, just killed via the `Close` statement (it just sends the `SIGKILL` signal on Linux).

**main.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with GNAT.Expect; use GNAT.Expect;
with GNAT.OS_Lib; use GNAT.OS_Lib;

procedure Main is

   Command : constant String := "python -u test.py 123";
   Pd      : Process_Descriptor;
   Args    : Argument_List_Access;
   Result  : Expect_Match;

begin

   Args := Argument_String_To_List (Command);

   Non_Blocking_Spawn
      (Pd,
       Command     => Args (Args'First).all,
       Args        => Args (Args'First + 1 .. Args'Last),
       Buffer_Size => 0);  

   for I in 1 .. 10 loop

      Expect (Pd, Result, Regexp => "\d+", Timeout => 2_000);

      case Result is    
         when Expect_Timeout =>
            Put_Line ("Expect timed out.");   
         when 1  =>
            Put_Line ("Received: " & Expect_Out_Match (Pd));
         when others =>
            raise Program_Error;            
      end case;

      Put_Line ("Doing other stuff...");

   end loop;

   Close (Pd);
   Free (Args);

exception
   when Process_Died =>

      Put_Line ("Process died.");
      Close (Pd);
      Free (Args);

end Main;
```

**test.py**

```
import sys
import time

while True:

    print(sys.argv[1])
    time.sleep(1)
```

**output**

```
$ ./main
Received: 123
Doing other stuff...
Received: 123
Doing other stuff...
Received: 123

(repeated another 7 times).
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.